# Where can I find the llvm -stats information

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am running the command line

```
opt test.bc -loop-vectorize -o test2.bc -stats
```

to check the statistics collected by the `LLVM` loop vectorize pass. However, after running the command, I only get the test2.bc without getting any stats printed. May I know where should I look for these stats?

Thanks in advance,
T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be printed on your terminal after the command has finished executing. However, your `LLVM` needs to be built with assertions enabled, documented [here](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-statistic-class-stats-option):

> Note that in order to use the ‘-stats‘ option, LLVM must be compiled
>   with assertions enabled.

This corresponds to this `cmake` flag, if you are building `LLVM` from source:

```
-DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On
```

Moreover, you can query a specific `LLVM` installation for its assertion mode using:

```
llvm-config --assertion-mode
```

If assertions are enabled, then it should return `ON`.

For code introspection of this feature, the corresponding preprocessor definition is

```
LLVM_ENABLE_STATS
```

or when [`NDEBUG`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) is **not** defined, as seen in the `include/llvm/Support/Statistic.h` header file.